# How to solve this error: Failed to create credentials

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm using Firebase UI to implement sign in in my Android application. I've followed the documentation in firebase

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui?authuser=1

Every thing seems to work correctly, but I got this error saying that Firebase was unable to build credentials and therefore the user is prompted to select which account to use to sign in.

And I can't figure out why or what is causing it.

At first I thought that it was an issue with the version I was using, so I upgrade it to the newest version which is 4.3.2. but the problem persist. What can I do to solve this issue?

Here is the Error I get:

```
2019-04-30 15:17:27.136 1629-1629/com.iphoideas.android.myorganization E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
    com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Failed to build credential.
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.viewmodel.smartlock.SmartLockHandler.saveCredentials(SmartLockHandler.java:76)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.credentials.CredentialSaveActivity.onCreate(CredentialSaveActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7032)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2943)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1630)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is probably not the right place to post this.  You might want to turn this into a bug report on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Comment: Yes, I've already did it. here's the issue; https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1628